# A-Frame 0.70: Animated Blender-Exported glTF 2.0 w/ Simple Rig Doesn't Render Correctly

Tags: blender, aframe, gltf

I'm creating an animation with a simple rig in Blender and using it A-Frame 0.70. I have a box with a lid that opens via Euler rotation, but all children of the armature rotate with the lid even if they are not supposed to animate. Wiring up the flaps to their respective bones also distorts the geometry of the flaps - but I am simplifying this problem to just the lid for now to try to understand what is happening.

Animation works fine in Blender and apparently works in UX3D.

Attempts to separate the mesh into pieces and de-parent them from the armature results in the de-parented meshes to not render at all despite exporting all objects.

Tried Blender 2.78c and 2.79 and virtually all combinations of glTF export options with latest Blender glTF 2.0 exporter from Khronos.

[Blender Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPp8T.png)

[A-Frame Demo](https://codepen.io/enesser/pen/ad750cee253066e8e192951bb07c362f)

```
<a-gltf-model cursor-listener id="gift" src="#rigged-gift" animation-mixer=""></a-gltf-model>
```

Blender source included in CodePen link

Appreciate any direction I can get on this problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved with Blender 2.8 and above.

Comment: if possible, please provide a link as a reference.